# Is it possible to integrate grapesjs into angularjs with a controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, grapesjs

#### JS

```js
var app = angular.module('CompanyProfile', []);

app.controller('CompanyProfileCtrl', function() {

      function init() {

        var editor = grapesjs.init({
              allowScripts: 1,
              showOffsets: 1,
              autorender: 0,
              noticeOnUnload: 0,
              container: "#gjs",
              height: "700px",
              fromElement: true,
              clearOnRender: 0,
              storageManager: {
                autoload: 0
              },
```

HOW can i make this possible? BTW i did not submit the whole code. Assume that is all there. Will is work?

Comment: Put it in a directive to assure the container element exists when you initialize

Comment: hey, can you please provide an example

Comment: There are examples of initializing third party scripts in directives all over the web and in this site as well

Comment: Questions asking for tutorials or examples is off-topic for Stackerflow. Instead show us what you have done and describe the problems you are having so far. To create custom AngularJS Directives, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Creating Custom Directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

Answer (score 0):

If grapesjs has been loaded on the page it should be available the same way jQuery is. You can check your scripts tags for this in your main view (usually index.html). You can download it if you haven't already from [here](https://grapesjs.com/docs/#quick-start).

Comment: is it possible if i can share you the whole code and youll understand. Cus im done the whole for grapejs part. Im just having issues integrating the angularjs controller

Comment: Your controller looks good from what I can tell. Have you been able to bind the module to the page? That might be the part you're having issues with.